# How to set up a profiling feature for a Python based org?

Tags: python-3.x

I am woking on an opensource org [EinsteinPy](https://github.com/einsteinpy/einsteinpy). We need to find out methods which are slow in order to JIT them.
Now we are just doing jit on functions which we know by experience are slow. But, we need to come up with a profiling method. It seems like a requirement in long term.

I have tried to set up profilers but it just creates files which other contributers will surely not find amusing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and nice project, what's the question though?

Comment: Now we are just doing jit on functions which we know by experience are slow.
But, we need to come up with a profiling method.
It seems like a requirement in long term.

Comment: Wouldn't simple time measurements be enough? Say implemented as decorator which repeats the run N times, similar to Jupyter Notebook's `timeit` magic.

Comment: Should we apply it to all methods so that some method takes more than a specefic time, it gives a warning of some sort? But if that's the case, is it a good practice to add additional decorators to each and every methods?
Sorry if I ask something naive, I am new to opensource.

Comment: It depends whether __you__ as maintainer want to test some functions or whether you want to push it to the end user (which I would highly discourage). If the time measurements are for you, you can apply it to every function you deem suspicious (or write some script which applies the decorator, automates testing or other ideas). You should log those information as well. Profiling would be suited best if you wanted to find bottlenecks in those functions, not measure how long those take.